# Using two DC Voltage Doublers in series to Quadruple the voltage?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, dc, boost

Are there any unexpected dangers or hurdles in using two capacitive voltage doublers in series to quadruple a DC voltage? The DC voltage originates from a LiPo battery and is then injected into the body as part of a biomedical device. The required current to go through the body is only 1mA, but you need a higher voltage to get there (6 to 12V).

Is this a better option than a boost converter in terms of cost? I am not sure efficiency is a factor here, since the device uses such a small amount of current and only needs to last for a few hours. Thanks.

Comment: Voltage doublers, or multipliers need AC, not DC input. You would have to first chop the voltage up. There are many ic´s, or ready made boards that will do that for you.

Comment: You can't increase a DC voltage using voltage doublers because they need AC voltages as input. What you need is a boost converter.

Comment: There are circuits that take a DC input and produce nearly twice the output voltage other than the classic boost circuit with a inductor, diode, output capacitor and switch but any circuit that  produces a DC output bigger than its input is active so requires AC at some point even if it is created locally within the circuit.  Please clarify, with a circuit diagram, what you mean by a voltage doubler.  I would hate to see a new user getting down voted and disillusioned because of a simple misunderstanding about terminology as most electronics engineers use it. A picture will clarify what mean.

Comment: You can upload images from a different web site or we have an excellent tool on the site to draw your own circuit diagram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already commented: No, beacause the ordinary doubler needs AC. But there exists more complex circuits for higher multplication factors.

Search for voltage multiplier circuits.

Here is a Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_multiplier